# Using Ajax to implement controller method which is passed an ID

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a button that toggles a boolean value in my DB table. It works but reloads the page each time, so I'd like to toggle it using AJAX. I'm not sure how to do an AJAX post request that can provide the controller with the ID it needs. This is what I have so far:

TaskController Method:

```
    public function updateCompleted($id)
{

    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    if($task->completed) {
        $task->completed = false;
    } else {
        $task->completed = true;
    }

    $task->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Task updated!');
    return redirect('tasks');
}
```

Button used to toggle (in this case, the first task with ID of 1):

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('TaskController@updateCompleted', $task->id))) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PATCH') }}

    @if ($task->completed)
        {{ Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit')) }}
    @else
        {{ Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger ajaxSubmit', 'type'=>'submit')) }}
    @endif

{{ Form::close() }}
```

AJAX that doesn't work...

```
    $('.ajaxSubmit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'tasks/complete/{id}',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log("working");
            }
        });
   });
```

And route:

```
Route::patch('tasks/complete/{id}', 'TaskController@updateCompleted');
```

How do I get the Ajax to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this 
add the id in hidden input with id of "myid" for example

```
  $('.ajaxSubmit').click(function(e) {
   var data = $("#myid").val();
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tasks/complete',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log("working");
        }
    });
   });
```

do this

```
 Route::post('tasks/complete', 'TaskController@updateCompleted');
```

don't forget CSRF .

Comment: I have tried this but now I am received a "405 (Method not Allowed)" error. As this is a patch request, I thought 'type' would need to be 'PATCH' so I've tried that, and it returns a '500 (Internal Server Error)'. Any ideas?

Comment: it's crsf propably, google it always happens with ajax request (comment the crsfmiddlware in app/http/kernel.php to see if its reaky the issue)